# How to export fuzzing report from ZAP with request and response?

Tags: security-testing, zapproxy, fuzz-testing

I'm doing fuzzing test on a project using OWASP ZAP.

After the test is completed, I export the results in CSV format from the Fuzzer tab in results.

This result doesn't have the Request and response. It only exports what is displayed in the Fuzzer tab.

Generate report also doesn't give this data for Fuzzing.

How can I export Fuzz testing report along with the respective request and response data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently in **OWASP ZAP** there is no direct way to export Fuzzer test report with request and response of each request.

So, what you can do is,

1. select a record from the *Fuzzer* tab.
2. Now, you can copy the *Request and Response* data of that perticular record from their respective tabs above.

This can become tedious to copy the data manually for all the test results. So, there is also a simple alternative.

Select all the records in the Fuzzer tab, then right click and then click on "***Save Selected Entries as HAR (HTTP Archive File)***".

This will export all the Fuzz testing records with their respective request and response data in a HAR file.

You can not read this HAR file using a text editor or IDE to get the data. The file contains all the data in a JSON format.

Comment: It would be really good if ZAP had a report export option for this. Anyways, the HAR export thing is a good workaround though. I can get a dev to write a script to read the JSON and display the data in a properly formatted report. Thank you.